# Google Drive permission "add but not edit"

Tags: google-drive-api, onedrive

Is there any way to do this?

I want a shared folder, which will be used for resources for a project, I want to allow my developer to add new files which I will then review and use, but not to edit existing ones as then it'll bypass my review. 
This is for security reasons.

Any ideas? If a solution exists for OneDrive I'd also accept it.

Answer (score 2):

No, that is currently not available. You can only give them edit permission, which includes add and edit.

The best way to achieve this is to script moving any added items into a private or view-only folder.

Answer (score 0):

You only have a few [permissions](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions) roles that you can set.

> - owner
> - writer
> - commenter
> - reader

So, there's no quick way to do that. What I can suggest is for you to [detect changes](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-changes) on the [folder](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/folder) (considered as file with the MIME type `application/vnd.google-apps.folder`) in which the file will be added, and then change the permission of that file to `reader`.

Hopefully the suggestion would be sufficient for your use case.

Happy coding!